# Nested catch operators

Tags: c++, exception

I need catch exceptions that are maybe thrown by code in try...catch construction, and do something depending on exception type. But also I want do some code if any exception are thrown.
I did so:

```
try
{
    // code
}
catch (...)
{
    try
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (exc1)
    {
        // handling
    }
    catch (exc2)
    {
        // handling
    }
    // here is code that are executed if any exception are thrown
}
```

My code works, but I want to know whether the Standard says anything about it.
Maybe is there any better method?

**UPD**: Sorry for the slow answers to comments. Simple, English is a second language for me.

**UPD**: I think that code from AdelNick or second code from Steve Jessop or second code from David Rodríguez - dribeas are right for me.

Comment: "My code works" -- how so? If the exception is neither `exc1` nor `exc2`, then "here is code that are executed if any exception are thrown" is not executed.

Comment: What do you mean with *executed if any exception is thrown*? Only `exc1` and `exc2`? *Any* exception at all? Any exception that is not `exc1` or `exc2`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Any exception at all.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is bad, because the `// here is code that are executed if any exception are thrown` part won't be executed if neither of `exc1` or `exc2` branch catch the exception. Your code is an equivalent version of the following:

```
try
{
    // code
}
catch (exc1)
{
    // handling
}
catch (exc2)
{
    // handling
}
// here is code that are executed if any exception are thrown
```

The `C++` language does not support a finally block, if that's what you're after. That is because an object's destructor is responsible for freeing resources, not a finally block. Here is [Stroustrup's explanation](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#finally) of the topic.

Answer (score 3):

You should write:

```
try
{
    // code
}
catch (exc1)
{
    // handling
}
catch (exc2)
{
    // handling
}
catch (...) 
{
    // here is code that are executed if any *other* exception are thrown
}
```

If you want particular code to be executed as part of all three cases then you have two options: call it in all three places, or do something like this:

```
bool threw = true;
try
{
    // code
    threw = false;
}
catch (exc1)
{
    // handling
}
catch (exc2)
{
    // handling
}
catch (...) {
}
if (threw) {
    // here is code that are executed if any exception are thrown
}
```

Comment: Why's this getting downvoted? It looks like the right answer to me. Some comments explaining why it's not would be useful.

Comment: If it's just that "catch(...)" swallows everything, the exception can be re-thrown after the 'any-case' code has run.

Comment: @Ben Hymers: the problem was that OP wanted one piece of code to run for every catched type of exception, to eliminate code duplication (as I understood the question). Steve's answer missed that originally.

Comment: @BenHymers: I picked up one or two downvotes at a point where my answer was certainly wrong: I didn't add "`*other*`" until a minute or so after posting and then made further edits. I'm still prepared to believe this isn't what the questioner wants. I probably should have waited for an answer to my comment on the question before answering, because I'm making assumptions that might be incorrect.

Comment: Ah, I see. Fair enough :)

Answer (score 1):

I would change the code order as following:

```
try
{
    try
    {
      // code
    }
    catch (exc1)
    {
        // handling
        throw; // edited. was: throw exc1;
    }
    catch (exc2)
    {
        // handling
        throw; // edited. was: throw exc2;
    }
} 
catch(...)
{
    // here is code that are executed if any exception are thrown
}
```

as it works if any other type of exception is thrown (not only **exc1** or **exc2**). Also if the code common for all exceptions is the resource releasing, consider using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) principle instead).

Comment: `throw exc;` inside an exception handler is bad practice, as it slices the exception object. If you want to _rethrow_ an exception just do `throw;`

Comment: Depending on what you want to do if the code in "handling" throws, the structure is either entirely right or entirely wrong :-) I agree with K-ballo about rethrowing, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comments it seems that you may be expecting something that won't happen, and that has already been discussed in other answers. But it could be a misunderstanding on our side. If the code inside the `try` can only throw one of `exc1` or `exc2` then yes, it will do what you expect.

From the comment update, it seems that the intention was to handle *any* exception, including those that are neither `exc1` nor `exc2`. For that purpose, the code won't do what is expected and `exc3` will propagate outside of the nested `try`s. Just flatten the two levels and add a `catch (...)` at the end.

---

*From here on the answer was based on a false assumption about the question.*

The pattern of rethrowing is supported by the standard and used commonly in situations where the handling of the exceptions in different contexts is the same to avoid code duplication:

```
void processException() {
   // implement exception handling in all contexts
   try {
     throw;
   } catch (exceptionType1 const & ex1) {
   } catch (exceptionType2 const & ex2) {
// } catch (...) {
   }
}
void f() {
   try {
      something();
   } catch (...) {
      processException();
   }
}
void g() {
   try {
      anotherThing();
   } catch (...) {
      processException();
   }
}
```

If the code to handle the exceptions is not going to be centralized for different functions, that pattern may complicate the code more than you need. You could consider a single try/catch with an extra control variable:

```
bool success = false;
try {
   doSomething();
   success = true;
} catch (exception1 const & ex1) {
...
} catch (exception2 const & ex2) {
...
// } catch (...) {
}
if (!success) {
   // common code to all exceptions
}
```

Comment: "Just flatten the two levels and add a catch (...) at the end." No. I want to execute code depending on exception type and execute another code if any exception (exc1, exc2 and any other) are thrown. For example: exc1 are thrown. I need to execute code that handle this exception. And then the code is executed if ex1, ex2 or other are thrown. I think that code from AdelNick or second code from Steve Jessop or your second code is right for me. Sorry if I wrote unclear. Thanks anyway!